# Expected number of $k$-patterns in a uniformly random $n$-permutation

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra

For an $n$-permutation $\pi\in S_n$, each of the $\binom{n}{k}$ restrictions of $\pi$ to $k$ entries induces a pattern $\sigma\in S_k$: for $\pi(a_1),\dots, \pi(a_k)$ with $a_1<\dots<a_k$, $\sigma(i)<\sigma(j)$ iff $\pi(a_i)<\pi(a_j)$.

Let $N_\sigma(\pi)$ be the number of times it occurs as a $k$-pattern in $\pi$ and let $P_\sigma(\pi)=N_\sigma(\pi)/\binom{n}{k}$.

For example, for $\pi=1234\in S_4$, if we restrict to the last three entries, it induces $\sigma=123$. And we have $N_\sigma(\pi)=4$.

Now if $\pi$ is chosen uniformly at random from $S_n$, $P_\sigma(\pi)$ becomes a random variable. I have a feeling that $\mathbb{E} P_\sigma = 1/k!$ for every $\sigma\in S_k$ by symmetry. But I am not sure how to prove it strictly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $k$-entry $K$ out of the $n$ places, let $\chi_K(\sigma)$ be the indicator random variable that at those $k$ entries, the random permutation $\pi$ induces $\sigma$.
Then
$$N_\sigma(\pi)=\sum_{K\subseteq [n]:|K|=k}\chi_K.$$
And we have
$$E\chi_K=P(\chi_K=1)=1/k!.$$
Therefore
$$EP_\sigma(\pi)= \binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k!}/\binom{n}{k}=1/k!.$$